# Strange behaviour, Generic ArrayList of Long

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have `someMethod()` which returns `Collection<Long>`.

```
ArrayList<Long> results = (ArrayList<Long>) someMethod();
Long value = results.get(0);
```

I get `ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`.
Trying `System.out.println(results.get(0));` in fact, it returns e.g. `[32]`.
I do not understand this. This is ArrayList of Long! Why `get(0)` returns `ArrayList`?

This helps:

```
Object o = results.get(0);
ArrayList<Long> al = (ArrayList<Long>) o;
Long val = al.get(0);
```

but why this is needed?

Comment: `someMethod` returns `Collection<ArrayList<Long>>`. `"[ 32 ]"` is equivalent to `ArrayList.toString()` for an `ArrayList` only containing `32`

Comment: Can we see the signature of `someMethod`?

Comment: `Collection<Long> someMethod(Collection<? extends SomeInterface> target)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly `someMethod()` is actually returning `Collection<List<Long>>`, violating declared return type. This is possible due to type erasure. The compiler is happy as long as the class type is correct, generic type can be ignored (the compiler will only raise warning). Basically this is a bug in `someMethod()`.